# How to run SWT application from SWT application?

Tags: java, swt

I have two SWT application. From app 1, I call app2:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("App2.bat");
```

App2 is runned but when getting display, it throws exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    no swt-win32-3740 in java.library.path
    no swt-win32 in java.library.path
    C:\Documents and Settings\Tran Dinh Thoai\.swt\lib\win32\x86\swt-win32-3740.dll: The referenced assembly is not installed on your system
    Can't load library: C:\Documents and Settings\Tran Dinh Thoai\.swt\lib\win32\x86\swt-win32.dll

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.escapenotes.updater.Checker.run(Checker.java:58)
    at com.escapenotes.updater.Runner.main(Runner.java:20)
```

When I call app2 (run App2.bat) from command line, it run well but it throws exception when running from app1. How can I run app2 from app1?

This is content of App2.bat:

```
  @echo off
  set JH=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
  set CP=C:\Data\Projects\EscapeNotes\extensions\Updater\bin
  set XNP="%CP%";"%CP%\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar";"%CP%\aws-java-sdk-1.0.007.jar";"%CP%\commons-codec-1.4.jar";"%CP%\commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar";"%CP%\jsoup-1.6.2.jar";"%CP%\log4j-1.2.8.jar";"%CP%\text.jar";"%CP%\jface.jar";"%CP%\jfacetext.jar";"%CP%\osgi.jar";"%CP%\runtime.jar";"%CP%\swt.jar"
  "%JH%\bin\java.exe" -cp %XNP% com.escapenotes.updater.Runner %1
```

When I added -Djava.library.path

```
@echo off
set JH=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
set CP=C:\Data\Projects\EscapeNotes\extensions\Updater\bin
set XNP="%CP%";"%CP%\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar";"%CP%\aws-java-sdk-1.0.007.jar";"%CP%\commons-codec-1.4.jar";"%CP%\commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar";"%CP%\jsoup-1.6.2.jar";"%CP%\log4j-1.2.8.jar";"%CP%\text.jar";"%CP%\jface.jar";"%CP%\jfacetext.jar";"%CP%\osgi.jar";"%CP%\runtime.jar";"%CP%\swt.jar"
"%JH%\bin\java.exe" -Djava.library.path="C:\Data\Projects\EscapeNotes\extensions\Updater\bin" -cp %XNP% com.escapenotes.updater.Runner %1
```

Although there is C:\Data\Projects\EscapeNotes\extensions\Updater\bin\swt-win32-3740.dll, I got exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    C:\Data\Projects\EscapeNotes\extensions\Updater\bin\swt-win32-3740.dll: The referenced assembly is not installed on your system
    no swt-win32 in java.library.path
    C:\Documents and Settings\Tran Dinh Thoai\.swt\lib\win32\x86\swt-win32-3740.dll: The referenced assembly is not installed on your system
    Can't load library: C:\Documents and Settings\Tran Dinh Thoai\.swt\lib\win32\x86\swt-win32.dll

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.escapenotes.updater.Checker.run(Checker.java:58)
    at com.escapenotes.updater.Runner.main(Runner.java:20)
```

Comment: Please add the content of `App2.bat` to your question.

Comment: I have added content of App2.bat to my question

Answer (score 0):

From the exception it looks like swt-win32 library is not defined by the java.library.path environment variable. In your "App2.bat" please provide it by the -D option like:

```
java -Djava.library.path=[path to your library]
```

Comment: I added -Djava.library.path but I got exception

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SnippetLauncher in the snippet project of the SWT sources. It demonstrates how to programmatically launch snippets.

```
https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/SnippetLauncher.java
```

The above works across platforms btw. I've used it on Linux and Windows.

Another thing to try is to copy the run-configuration of a terminated snippet. In the debug view, see the properties of a terminated run, it shows the command that was used to run the snippet. (I do this on Gtk, not sure if it works well on Windows).

Let me know if that solves things for you or if you have further questions.